# Explain FindTransientRepeat

Tags: list-manipulation

The documentation for `FindTransientRepeat` says:

> `FindTransientRepeat[`*list*`,`*n*`]`
>   returns a pair of lists `{`transient`,`repeat`}` where the elements of *repeat* 
>   occur successively at least *n* times at the end of *list*.

In view of that, I do not understand the output here:

```
    FindTransientRepeat[{a, b, c, d, c, d, c, d}, 2]
{{a, b}, {c, d}}
```

OK, the elements of `{c, d}` do occur successively at least twice. But what about the *transient* first entry, namely, `{a, b}` in the output — why is that?

Comment: According to the docs, `{a, b}` is the transient part.  That is, the part that is not repeated.

Comment: OK, I should have seen that. However while it is suggested by the function's name and is shown in the Examples section of the `ref/FindTransientRepeat` page, but *not* in the page 's initial description or the immediately following "Details and Options" section.

Comment: Fair enough. The lack of a complete description does leave one only with guessing what `transient` is. I posted an answer to the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems in the ***description*** of [`FindTransientRepeat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindTransientRepeat.html) in the synopses and details section, the only clue that the first component of the return value is the transient part is the name given to the symbol, namely `transient`:

> `FindTransientRepeat[list, n]` 
>   returns a pair of lists `{transient, repeat}` where the elements of `repeat` occur successively at least `n` times at the end of list.

Strictly speaking, then, there is not definition of what this part is, but apparently the documentation writer thought users would be able to infer what it was.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, it seems, that `transient` is the part of the `list`, that comes before the at least `n` repetitions of `repeat`.

See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindTransientRepeat.html

Comment: That seems like what I said: "... the first component of the return value is the transient part...."